# Set lower metric on wlan

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, metric

i've been looking for a solution for this for a while, hope you can help me.

I have a network at home like this.

```
                           +----------+           
                           | INTERNET |           
                           +-----+----+           
                                 |                
                           +-----+----+           
                           |  CABLE   |           
                           |  MODEM   |           
                           +-----+----+           
                                 |                
                      +----------+---------+      
                      |                    |      
                      |                    |      
                +-----v-----+        +-----v-----+
       +--------+  D-LINK   |        |  D-LINK   |
       |        |  DIR-600  |        |  DI-524   |
       |        +-----------+        +-----+-----+
       |              |                    |      
       |              |                    |      
       +        +-----+-----+              |      
192.168.2.XXX---> Windows7  |              |      
       +        |           |              |      
       |        +-----------+              |      
       +        |Ubuntu     |              |      
192.168.2.YYY +->Virtualbox <---Public IP ++      
                +-----------+
```

One Cable Modem with a Router (Dir-600) for local IPs, and an Access Point (DI-524) for public IPs.

On the local network i have a computer with Windows 7 and Virtualbox, In the virtualbox I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server. This server has internet conection on ETH0 with a bridged adapter, so it has a local IP like 192.168.2.XXX.

Also on the virtualbox i have set a wlan adapter with direct access to the virtual ubuntu server and connected to the DI-524 network with a public IP.

So, the ubuntu server has 2 interfaces:

ETH0 connected to local network with IP 192.168.2.XXX
WLAN1 connected to DI-524 with public IP.

What I want is:

Give WLAN1 the highest priority for internet access. And only if there is no WLAN connection, the virtual machine can access internet through ETH0.

I know it can be done changing metrics, but don't know how, i've tried many commands but nothing seems to work.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that via ifmetric package install it on ubuntu then set number for example 10 to wlan0 and number 20 for eth0 it mean the highest priority number for wlan0 highest priority is 0 by default (priority denotes metric) check this topic [enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/501406/make-networkmanager-prefer-ethernet-over-wifi-if-both-present)

but plz check your metric first via

route -n

then you can delete old metrics via something like this command

sudo route del -net default gw 192.168.2.XX netmask 0.0.0.0 dev wlan0 metric 0

Comment: route -n shows both metrics as 0, and ifconfig shows both as 1.

Comment: no route -n denotes (numeric) for example 0.0.0.0 it can be (default) the meaning of default default route mean any source or any destination .